# Proof of Murphy’s law

Tags: probability

Does there exist mathematical proof of Murphy’s law ?

And  how to prove or disprove Murphy’s law ?

Anything that can go wrong, will go wrong.

Comment: "Is such and such mathematically provable" is a mathematical statement. It happens that many consider the answer to this question obviously "no," but that doesn't make the question nonmathematical

Answer (score 3):

No there does not. Muphy's Law is not a mathematical, logical, or statistical fact. Sometimes it fails to attain. Instead, it's a pessimistic assumption that guides our preparations. If you live as if it is true, then you'll be more prepared if things go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Murphy's law means that anything that can go wrong will go wrong in any given trial, I think.

But it's easy to prove mathematically that if the probability of a certain wrong thing W is $p>0$ then with probability $1$ it will go wrong in at least once in infinitely many trials. The probability that on the other hand it never goes wrong is $$(1-p)(1-p)...=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an interesting well written article

http://people.howstuffworks.com/murphys-law.htm

and here another one with facts applied to mathematics

http://www.pleacher.com/mp/mhumor/murphy.html

I personally like this one: "every solution breeds new problems", found here

https://www.maths.nottingham.ac.uk/personal/ibf/some.html

And know a person that happened this one

"Truck deliveries that normally take one day will take five when you are waiting for the truck"!